# $\sum_{cyc} \alpha(\alpha + a)(\alpha^2 +a+b) = 4$ where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ are the roots of $x^4 + ax^3 + (a+b)x^2 + a(a + b)x - 1$

Tags: polynomials

**Problem:** Suppose a momnic polynomial $ x^4 + ax^3 + (a+b)x^2 + a(a + b)x - 1  $ has roots $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$. Then prove that

$$ \sum_{cyc} \alpha(\alpha + a)(\alpha^2 +a+b) = 4 $$

I attempted to expand the given sum and then use standard methods to find summation of these $\alpha^2$,$\alpha^3$,$\alpha^4$ etc but it turned out to be hopelessly long. I don't know how can I proceed further. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have :
$$\alpha^4+a\alpha^3 +(a+b)\alpha^2 +a(a+b)\alpha-1=0$$

$$\alpha(\alpha^3+a\alpha^2 +(a+b)\alpha +a(a+b))=1$$

$$\alpha(\alpha^2(\alpha+a)+(a+b)(\alpha+a))=1$$

$$\alpha(\alpha+a)(\alpha^2+a+b)=1$$

Therfore:
$$\sum_{cyc} \alpha(\alpha + a)(\alpha^2 +a+b) = 4$$